# absolute div not inheriting height of relative parent with fixed height

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

I have a `th` and a `div` inside it. the `th` is positioned relative and the child `div` is positioned `absolute`. (see div class="horizontal")

The child `div` is not inheriting the parent height in percentage as you can see in the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gaurav5430/fmrWj/1/

As per my knowledge, the `absolute div` should inherit its dimensions from its bounding-box, which can be a relative element with a specific height, which i think is the case here.

P.S : tested in IE9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue with placing absolute positioned elements inside a table-cell ([have a read of this](http://css-tricks.com/absolutely-position-element-within-a-table-cell/)).  As you have a height set on your `th` you are able to add a buffer div in:

```
<tr>
    <th><div class="relative"><div class="axesTitle">Parameter</div></div></th>
    <th><div class="relative"><div class="horizontal">Q4 '14 ghfggfdf</div></div></th>
    <th><div class="relative"><div class="horizontal">QoQ</div></div></th>
    <th><div class="relative"><div class="horizontal">YTD</div></div></th>
</tr>
```

And then use the following styles:

```
th div.relative {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}
```

And this should allow you to set a height for your absolute - have a look at your js console in the following example and you will see the height is set to 40:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/fmrWj/3/)

Comment: Thank you so much. I had a similar issue inside a bootstrap column. The relative wrapper worked its magic!

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't want to use tables, use `height: inherit`. In my case, the problem was that the **parent (B)** had a percentage height of its *parent (A)* so when using absolute positioning, the absolute child of **B** needed to be 100% of **B** but ended up being 100% of the body.

Check the sample below (this seems to only work when the parent has something set for height):

```css
#parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#child-not-absolue-or-fixed {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 100%;
}
#child-absolue-or-fixed {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 80px;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child-not-absolue-or-fixed"></div>
  <div id="child-absolue-or-fixed"></div>
</div>
```